# Unexpected t-string error in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-error

This is the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
>   /home/kttoman/public_html/wp-config.php on line 28

And this is the line 28 of the php file:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost’);
```

Sure its only a little something, just any help or suggestions would be most helpful.

Comment: Missing `;` on the line before...?

Comment: Make use of source code editors with syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a curly quote mixed in:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost’);
                            ^ right there
```

change to

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

---

*Plus*, if you have made a copy/paste for any other defined lines (unshown), you will need to change those also.

Comment: how did you spot that. :)

Comment: @TomeӾsanS From experience ;) I used to be an text/book editor/proofreader many years ago for printing companies.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Bet you just saw it because of syntax highlighting.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois No Charlotte, the text on my screen appears quite large. I can see the differences quite well. :)

Comment: @CharlotteDunois To add, and you would have been right had the question not been edited for not being indented right away. It was edited by Tasos K. after I saw the error. The time it took me to type up my answer is why the timestamps are close.

Comment: Well spotted! You were also correct in other defined lines that I didn't show, some were curly quotes. Thanks for pointing that out, pays to check over everything.

Comment: @JoshFrench You're welcome Josh, glad I could help. I like to think ahead just in case ;)